# Formula for A119016 : Numerators of "Farey fraction" approximations to $\sqrt{2}$

Tags: sequences-and-series

Can someone please verify and maybe simplify the closed formula for [A119016](http://oeis.org/A119016) :

$$ a(n)=\frac{1}{4} \left(1+\sqrt{2}\right)^{n/2} \left((-1)^n+1\right)+\frac{1}{2}
   \left(\sqrt{2}-1\right)^{n/2} \cos \left(\frac{\pi  n}{2}\right)
   +\frac{1}{4 \sqrt{8119+5741\sqrt{2}}} \left(58+41 \sqrt{2}\right) \left(1+\sqrt{2}\right)^{n/2} \left(1-(-1)^n\right)-2 \left(140+99
   \sqrt{2}\right) \left(\sqrt{2}-1\right)^{n/2} \sin \left(\frac{\pi  n}{2}\right) $$

Considering even and odd functions I could simplify the formula to :
$$
   a(n)=\frac{1}{4} \left(\sqrt{2}-2\right) \left(1+\sqrt{2}\right) \left(1-(-1)^n\right)
   \left(\left(1-\sqrt{2}\right)^{\frac{n-1}{2}}-\left(1+\sqrt{2}\right)^{\frac{n-1}{2}}\right)+\frac{1
   }{4} \left((-1)^n+1\right) \left(\left(1-\sqrt{2}\right)^{n/2}+\left(1+\sqrt{2}\right)^{n/2}\right)
   $$

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

One observation is that 
$$\cos\left(\frac{\pi n}2\right)=\left\{\begin{array}{cc}(-1)^{n/2}& n\equiv0,2(\mod4)\\0&n\equiv1,3(\mod4)  \end{array}\right.$$
and
$$\sin\left(\frac{\pi n}2\right)=\left\{\begin{array}{cc}(-1)^{n/2}& n\equiv1,3(\mod4)\\0&n\equiv0,2(\mod4)  \end{array}\right.$$

Comment: yes, also only taking the formula from $a(n)=1/4$ .. to .. $cos( \pi n / 2)$ you will notice that this represents the sequence A001333 for $n$ odd.